# Angular 2, POST response map error?

Tags: typescript, angular2-services

My following code works correctly when I take a good response from server

```
let response = this.http.post(url,sendData).map(res =>res.json());
return response;
```

but, as soon as I get a non-JSON response from server, the whole app starts breaking down.

Assuming that ***.json()*** gives this error i try/catch.

```
let response:any = this.http.post(url,sendData);
return response.map((resp)=>{      
      try{
        resp.json();
      }
      catch(Error){
        return *what to do*;
      }

      return resp.json();
    });
```

**Full Code Reference**

```
 sendToAPI(sendData,param,option?){

    sendData = JSON.stringify(sendData);
    let url = this.link+param;

    let response:any = this.http.post(url,sendData);        
    return response.map((resp)=>{      
      try{
        resp.json();
      }
      catch(Error){
        ** here ** // need to return a response object
      }
      return resp.json();
    });
  }
```

> What could be the possible way out? When due to some reason API gives a non-JSON parsable error. I should give me an object of this following sort to *subscribe* to:

```
{
    status: 0,
    data: [],
    message : "non json response by server"
  }
```

Comment: .catch() is not working

Comment: have you tried adding a `.catch(err)` to your `http.post`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one way to do it in your current set up would be something like this:

```
let response:any = this.http.post(url,sendData);        
    return response.map((resp)=>{
      let body = {};
      try{
        body = resp.json();
      }
      catch(Error){
        body = {
            status: 0,
            data: [],
            message : "non json response by server"
        };
      }
      return body;
    });
```

Comment: Not exactly but works perfectly with small changes. Thanks.